# Multiplicação de matriz em C

Tags: c

estou com um probleminha nesse programa,
eu preciso em uma matriz[4][4] achar o minimo máximo de cada linha e multiplicar por cada numero da linha, em meu programa ele tem um erro de sintaxe, pois eu guardo o maior numero e ele multiplica somente pelo ultimo numero de cada linha por exemplo:

```
mat[i][j]={0, 1, 2, 3,
           4, 5, 6, 7,
           8, 9, 10, 11,
           12, 13, 14, 15}
```

ficaria:

```
 mat[i][j]={0, 1, 2, 9,
            4, 5, 6, 49,
            8, 9, 10, 121,
            12, 13, 14, 225}
```

meu codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

//achar maior menor de cada linha da matriz
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int mat[4][4];
    int i, j, aux;

    //le matriz
    for(i=0; i<=3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=3; j++)
        {
            setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
            printf("digite um numero para a posição %d e coluna %d de mat:\n", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    //1ºfase de processamento
    for(i=0; i<=3; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<=3; j++)
    {
        if(mat[i][j]>=mat[i][j])//se o elemento na posição mat={i,j} 
                                //for maior que o ultimo elemento da linha
        {
            aux=mat[i][j];//guardar em aux
            mat[i][j]=mat[i][j]*aux;
        }
    }
}
```

caso alguém souber o que eu fiz de errado, gostaria de alguma explicação estou tendo muito problema de sintaxe.

Comment: `if(mat[i][j]>=mat[i][j])` vai ser sempre verdade!

Comment: @pmg mas viu como eu faço pra descobrir o maior numero de cada linha?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando `j` for 3, o `if` vai aceder a um elemento inexistente

```
if(mat[i][j]>=mat[i][j+1]) // mat[i][4] nao existe
```

Comment: eu tinha modificado no meu IDE e postei o codigo errado na fase de processamento o foz se encontra se encontra de forma diferente modifiquei no post